# How to center a flexible box in the document?

Tags: css, flexbox

Today, while working with flexible box model in FF4, I noticed that I can't center a container in the document using `margin: 0 auto;`.

Does anybody know any way of centering this container? In Webkit it works as expected.

Comment: You should show a more complete example of your code.  Show the HTML and CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

for FF

```
display: -moz-box;
-moz-box-orient: horizontal;
-moz-box-pack: center;
-moz-box-align: center;
```

for normal case

```
display: box;
box-orient: horizontal;
box-pack: center;
box-align: center;
```